# MySQL LIMIT ignored in correlated subquery

Tags: mysql, limit, correlated-subquery

I have 2 tables: `orders` and `items`.  Each `order` has many `items`.  Each `item` has a `type`. I want a query that returns all orders where the MOST RECENT item has `type = 2`

I can build a correlated EXISTS clause that filters to orders where ANY of the items has `type=2`

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL 
    FROM items 
    WHERE order_id = orders.id
    AND type=2 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

but for the life of me, I can't seem to formulate a query to filter orders to those whose MOST RECENT item has type=2

I've also tried every combination of JOIN to attempt to overcome the LIMIT clause being ignored.  Nothing works.

I feel like this should be simple.

Comment: Wouldn't the first item in an Order have lowest `id` value out of the rest ? You have a `DESC` sort to get the first id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need to use `Exists()` clause. You can directly compare the result of correlated subquery to a value (`2`) in the `Where`. I am assuming the definition of "FIRST item" from your attemped query (`ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`). Try the following query:

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM orders AS o 
WHERE 2 = (SELECT type 
           FROM items 
           WHERE order_id = o.id 
           ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

---

- **Alternatively,** you can use the [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) in the `Select` clause itself, to get the first item type value for an order.
- You can then use this result in a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) and filter out the cases where first item type = 2.

Try the following:

```
SELECT dt.* 
FROM 
(
 SELECT o.*, 
        (SELECT type 
         FROM items 
         WHERE order_id = o.id 
         ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS first_item_type
 FROM orders AS o 
) AS dt 
WHERE dt.first_item_type = 2
```

Comment: Brilliant use of correlated subquery in the WHERE clause!  Very useful and it works!  I was also able to do `WHERE (SELECT type FROM items WHERE order_id = o.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) = 2`.  Presumably this is OK because all my `items` are guaranteed to have a `type`.